# product_attribute.info magento Uncaught SoapFault exception: [3] Invalid api path

Tags: magento, soap

I try to use the "product_attribute.info" to access the API in magento and is returning:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [3] Invalid api path. in... on line 81

Where is returning `return $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_attribute.info', $attributeId);`

Even replacing the function given by $attributeId gives correct this error.
I imagine that some file is corrupted on my server, but do not know which one is responsible.

I thank

EDIT: My Api.php

```
    class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Api extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Api_Resource
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_storeIdSessionField = 'product_store_id';
        $this->_ignoredAttributeCodes[] = 'type_id';
        $this->_ignoredAttributeTypes[] = 'gallery';
        $this->_ignoredAttributeTypes[] = 'media_image';
    }

    public function items($setId)
    {
        $attributes = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()
                ->loadAllAttributes()
                ->getSortedAttributes($setId);
        $result = array();

        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            /* @var $attribute Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute */
            if ( (!$attribute->getId() || $attribute->isInSet($setId))
                && $this->_isAllowedAttribute($attribute)) {

                if (!$attribute->getId() || $attribute->isScopeGlobal()) {
                    $scope = 'global';
                } elseif ($attribute->isScopeWebsite()) {
                    $scope = 'website';
                } else {
                    $scope = 'store';
                }

                $result[] = array(
                    'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId(),
                    'code'         => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
                    'type'         => $attribute->getFrontendInput(),
                    'required'     => $attribute->getIsRequired(),
                    'scope'        => $scope
                );
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function options($attributeId, $store = null)
    {
        $storeId = $this->_getStoreId($store);
        $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->getResource()
            ->getAttribute($attributeId)
            ->setStoreId($storeId);

        /* @var $attribute Mage_Catalog_Model_Entity_Attribute */
        if (!$attribute) {
            $this->_fault('not_exists');
        }
        $options = array();
        if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
            foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions() as $optionId=>$optionValue) {
                if (is_array($optionValue)) {
                    $options[] = $optionValue;
                } else {
                    $options[] = array(
                        'value' => $optionId,
                        'label' => $optionValue
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Comment: does your api user have permission to access this resource?

Comment: Yes, including any use functionality that works, just "product_attribute.info" returns error.

Comment: ok check if app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Api.php exists and it has an info method. this is what you are calling and make sure that your user has access to: catalog/product/attribute/info

Comment: I'll post the class below, because the characters are limited. EDIT:I included top